# TSOCKS error on Backtrack 5 Linux

Tags: linux, proxy, backtrack

I am running Backtrack 5 and when I tried installing `tsocks` with [this tutorial](http://corvillus.com/2006/09/18/how-to-set-up-tor-and-privoxy-on-ubuntu-linux/) (which was intended for Ubuntu, but I couldn't find one for Backtrack).

When I go through the steps and I try to run

```
tsocks ftp matthewdowney20.comyyr.com
```

… it returns:

```
root@root:~# tsocks ftp matthewdowney20.comyyr.com
06:47:53 libtsocks(9148): Only one default SOCKS server may be specified at line 50 in configuration file
06:47:53 libtsocks(9148): Server type may only be specified once for default server, at line 51 in configuration file
06:47:53 libtsocks(9148): Server port may only be specified once for default server, at line 52 in configuration file
06:47:53 libtsocks(9148): Error 111 attempting to connect to SOCKS server (Connection refused)
ftp: connect: Connection refused
ftp>
```

Comment: `tsocks ping google.com` returns `tsocks ftp matthewdowney20.comyyr.com`?

Comment: Also, what does your configuration file say?